# Docusign Cannot Post Templates using Docusign Api

Tags: docusignapi

i was trying to post templates on docusign api, but the only response is bad request, here's how i i post the data and files (php and guzzle 5)

```
$data = [
        'emailsubject' => 'Agreement for ' . $config['deal_name'],
        'documents' => [
          [
            'name' => $config['deal_name'],
            'documentId' => $config['deal_id']
          ]
        ],
        'recipients' => [
            'signers' =>
            [
              [
                'roleName' => Config::get('templateRoleName')
              ]
            ]
        ],
        'envelopeTemplateDefinition' => [
            'name' => $config['deal_name'],
        ],
        new \GuzzleHttp\Post\PostFile($config['deal_name'], Flysystem::readStream($config['doc_path'])),
    ];

    $res = $this->client->createRequest('POST',"$this->baseUrl/templates", [
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data',
            'X-DocuSign-Authentication' => json_encode([
                'Username' => Config::get('docusign.email'),
                'Password' => Config::get('docusign.password'),
                'IntegratorKey' => Config::get('docusign.integratorKey')
            ]),
        ],
        'body' => [
          'emailsubject' => 'Agreement for ' . $config['deal_name'],
          'documents' => [
            [
              'name' => $config['deal_name'],
              'documentId' => $config['deal_id']
            ]
          ],
          'recipients' => [
              'signers' =>
              [
                [
                  'roleName' => Config::get('templateRoleName')
                ]
              ]
          ],
          'envelopeTemplateDefinition' => [
              'name' => $config['deal_name'],
              'shared' => false
          ],
          new \GuzzleHttp\Post\PostFile($config['deal_name'], Flysystem::readStream($config['doc_path'])),
        ]
    ]);


    $response = $this->client->send($res);
```

I think that request is already same as in https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST API References/Post Template.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____130

Im already implement login, sent signed request from envelope id, but stuck on post templates ( upload data & pdf ), am i missing something?
Here's the error response

```
Client error response [url] https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/asdfaccountId/templates [status code] 400 [reason phrase] Bad Request
```

Here's the data posted to docusign api, (file section truncated)

```
POST /restapi/v2/accounts/blablaAccountId/templates HTTP/1.1 Host: demo.docusign.net Content-Type: application/json X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"blabla@blabla.com","Password":"blabla","IntegratorKey":"blabla"} User-Agent: Guzzle/5.3.0 curl/7.35.0 PHP/5.6.17-3+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 --56af2bf9b3fb2 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="emailsubject" Agreement for asdf --56af2bf9b3fb2 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="documents[0][name]" asdf --56af2bf9b3fb2 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="documents[0][documentId]" asdf --56af2bf9b3fb2 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="envelopeTemplateDefinition[name]" asdf --56af2bf9b3fb2 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="envelopeTemplateDefinition[shared]" --56af2bf9b3fb2 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="asdf"; filename="f2EQySRYpYyGngxuw0bM"
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i'm figured it out. I missed the error message. When post field data for creating templates, recipientId is required

```
        'recipients' => [
            'signers' =>
            [
              [
                'roleName' => Config::get('templateRoleName'),
                  //it will not work if recipient id is not set
                'recipientId' => 1,
              ]
            ]
        ],
```

However another fun thing happened, we also need to provide form boundary,

Because i cant set it via guzzle, then i hard code the request body. 
Here's my code, hope its can help someone.

https://gist.github.com/nsulistiyawan/9ffcc04bc54aa93b574a